# How to mock IServiceProvider and still allow CreateInstance of generic types?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I'm attempting to unit test a bit of code that uses a combination of `IServiceProvider` and reflection to create an instance of each class that extends an abstract class `BaseCommand`:

```
IEnumerable<BaseCommand> commandsInAssembly = typeof(BaseCommand)
    .Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseCommand)) && !t.IsAbstract)
    .Select(t => (BaseCommand)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(_serviceProvider, t))
    .ToList();
```

The tricky part here is that `_serviceProvider` is injected and need's to be mocked (I think), to allow this bit of code to run successfully and in isolation. Each command needs access to DI to resolve its dependencies. Most commands look similar to:

```
public SomeCommand(IAppState appState, ILoggerAdapter<SomeCommand> logger) : base(appState)
```

I'm able to Mock `IServiceProvider` well enough to resolve `IAppState`, but I am having difficulty with `ILoggerAdapter<>`. Here is my current setup:

*Unit Test Constructor*

```
var serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();

serviceProvider
    .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(IAppState)))
    .Returns(new AppState());

serviceProvider
    .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(ILoggerAdapter<>)))
    .Returns(typeof(LoggerAdapter<>));

var serviceScope = new Mock<IServiceScope>();
serviceScope
    .Setup(x => x.ServiceProvider)
    .Returns(serviceProvider.Object);

var serviceScopeFactory = new Mock<IServiceScopeFactory>();
serviceScopeFactory
    .Setup(x => x.CreateScope())
    .Returns(serviceScope.Object);

serviceProvider
    .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory)))
    .Returns(serviceScopeFactory.Object); var mocker = new AutoMocker();

_commandDispatcher = new CommandDispatcher(serviceProvider.Object, _mockAppState.Object, _mockLogger.Object);
```

Which generates the following error:
**System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'ILoggerAdapter`1[SomeCommand]' while attempting to activate 'SomeCommand'.**

If I try to be more explicit with my setup (which I would like to avoid, it makes the test much more brittle) and use:

```
serviceProvider
    .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(ILoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>)))
    .Returns(typeof(LoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>));
```

But that generates an error as well: **System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type 'ILoggerAdapter`1[SomeCommand]'.**

I'm reading that either using AutoMocking containers or a Fixture may be more appropriate, but I'm unsure of where to start. I'm fairly new to unit testing in C#.

**How do I mock/provide `IServiceProvider` to my SUT without `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider, type)` blowing up?**

Comment: I think, if you're finding this too hard to test, I would suggest that you've not architected it in the best way

Comment: That's possible. I was hoping it was more of an issue with my lack of testing experience. This feels like a simple moq configuration issue that I just don't quite grasp.

Comment: So I wouldn't be worried so much that the correct instance is created, more that you should do `mock.Setup(foo => foo.CreateInstance(It.Is<SomeType>())).Returns(new MyMockType);` then doing two checks, first is `mock.Verify()` to make sure the method is called, second is to check the instance is of type MyMockType

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
serviceProvider
    .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(ILoggerAdapter<>)))
    .Returns(typeof(LoggerAdapter<>));
```

The problem with this setup is that `typeof(ILoggerAdapter<>)` is never being resolved, it's a generic type so `ILoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>` will be resolved.

```
serviceProvider
    .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(ILoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>)))
    .Returns(typeof(LoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>));
```

With this setup you are *resolving* the right service. However you are *returning* the wrong result as you are returning the `Type` instance that represents `LoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>`, not an *instance* of `LoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>`. You will need to create an instance of `LoggerAdapter<SomeCommand>` either by `new`-ing it up or mocking it as well.

---

Another solution might be that you don't mock the `IServiceProvider` instance but instead create a "real" `IServiceProvider` instance using the regular DI setup: create a new `ServiceCollection` instance, add your services and call `BuildServiceProvider()`. For example:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
// Add IAppState, ILoggerAdapater, and other services

// Create the service provider instance
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// Resolve services from the IServiceProvider and pass it along
var appState = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAppState>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SUT doesn't call IServiceProvider's methods, so there shouldn't be any need to mock them at all. All you want to test, is whether the SUT passes `_serviceProvider` and `t` to `CreateInstance` for each BaseCommand's concrete subclass.

One way to do that is to convert the static method `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` into an injectable dependency of `CommandDispatcher`, for example

```
interface IActivator
{
    object CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type t)
}
```

Then the test might look like this

```
pivate class TestCommand : BaseCommand
{
    public TestCommand(Type realCommandType)
    {
    }
}

// ...

// that's all the IServiceProvider mocking you need
var serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();

var activator = new Mock<IActivator>();
activator.Setup(_ => _.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, It.IsAny<Type>())
    .Returns<IServiceProvider, Type>((sp, t) => new TestCommand(t));

// ...

foreach (var expectedType in typeof(CommandDispatcher).Assembly.GetTypes()
   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseCommand)) && !t.IsAbstract))
{
    // check, whether whatever you do with commandsInAssembly 
    // contains a TestCommand with expectedType 
}
```

Comment: I think this simplifies the mocking code significantly, and makes a lot of sense. The only part that feels weird to me is injecting the static method to make this approach possible. I'm not sure if I'd be making the change _only_ to make testing easier, or if it's the better design decision as well, and the testing issue illuminates that.